# Получение ввода из двух USB клавиатур, можно ли определить источник?

Tags: delphi, windows, клавиатура

Получаю ввод из двух USB клавиатур (или MSR).
Как узнать из какого источника пришел ввод?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060512/how-to-distinguish-multiple-keyboards-in-delphi